# Strange intermittent popping sound from floorboards

Tags: flooring

I hear a strange sound from the floorboards. I made a recording of it which you can hear here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idaOVQx1O4OhvbT2lnnJm-lqSgdSJrQJ/view?usp=sharing

Here is what I know about the sound:

- It happens only at night (which makes it specially annoying since it disturbs my sleep and makes it harder to diagnose).
- It happens at irregular intervals. Sometimes I will go hours without hearing it and sometimes I will hear it several times in a minute.
- It comes from a part of the floor which has loose floorboards.
- It comes from a part of the floor next to the heater.

I have a wooden floor. What could be causing this sound?

Comment: Expansion and contraction due to fluctuating   temperatures and humidity levels.

Comment: Make that an answer, @Kris

Comment: Maybe try putting a carpet over that area.  Won't stop the sounds but could serve to muffle it enough so as not to bother you at night.

Comment: I tried that, the sound was too loud to be muffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kris said it's most likely:
Expansion and contraction due to fluctuating   temperatures and humidity levels.

There are several options to address this:
If you own the house, and want "a squeek free floor" hire it out to a local handyman.
Otherwise you will play chase the squeek for weeks with a mix of screws, nails, glue and braces.

If you don't own the property, call the owner.

Comment: There is a product called Squeek-No-More that might help...once you find the source of the squeaks.

Comment: @SteveWellens I can live with the squeaks. It's the popping sound which disturbs my sleep (recording of sound is in the question).

Comment: The holes in the flooboards through which the heating pipes pass were too small. After expanding them, the sound is gone.